# What is the best way to carry data over between onPause & onResume?

Tags: android

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to pass simple values from onPause and onResume in the Android activity lifecycle. I understand how to use get and put extra bundles for activity to activity data, but does that work for passing data between the same activity? Should i used SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to store the transient state of your application override [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [`onRestoreInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

These aren't lifecycle methods so are not always called.  They are used by the system so an `Activity` looks like how the user left it if they go away and come back to it.  If the User explicitly terminates the application - for example, by pressing the Back button - they are not called, so you should not use them for writing persistent user data.

If you want [to record persistent data you have several options](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html):

- Shared Preferences
- Internal Storage
- External Storage
- SQLite Databases

The one to use will depend on the data you want to store.

Comment: Also, for the specific case of screen rotations, there is `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`.